# label, goto commands in drracket

Tags: label, racket, goto

Are there any packages for label, goto, jump commands in drracket?

The [Control](https://docs.racket-lang.org/control-manual/index.html) package gives the following error:

```
 (let ([x 1])
    (let/ec return
      (begin/goto
        (label l1)
        (set! x (+ x 1))
        (when (= x 10000000)
          (return x))
        (goto l1)
        2)))
```

> goto: undefined;
>
> cannot reference undefined identifier

Need to simulate label, goto/jump for running code in LLVM IR, so rewriting using loops is not an option.

Comment: Rewrite using loops?

Comment: Conversion from `goto` to `loop` cannot be automated, so won't suit my purpose

Comment: The control package has now been updated. Please try it and let me know if it doesn't work (there might be a slight delay from updating on Github to the package server picking up on it). 

Racket "recently" switched to a new macro expander. The control package is rather old, so it was using tricks that worked on the the old expander and not on the new.

Answer (score 5):

First: it's clear that soegaard's  Control package is not working correctly, and I'm guessing it's because of the updates to the Syntax system that have been happening over the last few years.

Second: if you're simulating LLVM, you don't need labels and gotos. Just break up the code into basic blocks, and model each basic block as a function. Then every goto becomes a function call. You can definitely automate this.

Sorry to be terse. Let me know if you need more detail.

Comment: Yep - something must have happened with the new expander. I'll take a look. Also:tagging only works for people already in the discussion (as far as I know).